# multiprocessing: Mapping a function using a list of Processes instead of a Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a multiprocessing task that, in its simplest form, looks like the following:

```
def fun(x):
     y = setup()
     return y.f(x) 

pool = mp.Pool(4)
pool.map(fun, my_list)
```

However, the `setup()` is expensive and so I only want to do it once in each process, as opposed to doing it once per item in `my_list`.

I also do *not* want to pickle `y` and send it into each process, in this instance I require that the setup occurs within each process separately.

Hence, I could do something like this to set up each process:

```
class MyProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = setup()

    def fun(x):
        return self.y.f(x)

workers = [MyProcess() for _ in range(4)]
```

Is there any way I can now use workers as if it was a Pool? i.e. mapping some worker's `worker.fun` to each item in `my_list`? Ideally, I would want something like this:

```py
for result in workers.imap_unordered(MyProcess.fun, my_list):
    # do something
```

I suspect a solution using a Queue would also work, but I'm not entirely sure how I can implement this.

Comment: Every process runs in its own memory space (including the main one), so your class will not work because the initialization isn't being done in the memory=space of the process that will use its `fun()` member. You might be able to do what you by using a [`multiprocess.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers).

Comment: Is your question "how do I use a list of processes as a pool", or is it "how do I initialise processes of a pool"?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi either one would be a solution to my problem

Answer (score 1):

A [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) already supports customising each process at startup. Define an initialiser of the Pool processes that creates `y` and makes it accessible:

```
def init_process():
    global y     # make y accessible to everything
    y = setup()  # ... and initialise it

def fun(x):
     # use already initialised y
     return y.f(x) 

pool = mp.Pool(4, initializer=init_process)
pool.map(fun, my_list)
```

Comment: This could potentially work (even if I'm not a fan of global variables). If I, for example, want to later add another another variable to the state of each process, is there a way to do that?

Comment: The initializer can run arbitrary code, and as such define arbitrary many variables.

Comment: Sorry, I meant running essentially another initializer to update a second variable z at a later time, for example after running `pool.map()` once. Is that possible?

Comment: @mxbi That's not an initializer then. It could be that you are looking for the wrong mechanism, and want caching/memoization instead to avoid re-running functions. Of course, simply opening a new pool with another initialiser suitable for the second task may be sufficient.

Comment: No, I want to periodically send new state from the main process to the workers (between `map` calls) - this state can't be calculated on the workers. But I guess I could destroy them and create new ones (at a performance cost)

Answer (score 0):

To initialize processes in the pool when they are created you can use `initializer` and `initargs` [parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) of `Pool`.

An example to illustrate the approach:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

init_obj = {}


def setup(a):
    global init_obj
    init_obj = {"one": a}


def fun(x):
    y = init_obj
    print(y)


pool = mp.Pool(None, initializer=setup, initargs=(1,))
pool.map(fun, [0, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel that you could still use a pool:

```
def fun(x)
    y = setup()
    return [y.f(item) for item in x]

processes = 4
newlist = []
for i in range(processes):
    mylist[i * len(mylist)//4: (i + 1) * len(mylist)//4]
    newlist.append(mylist)

pool = mp.Pool(4)
pool.map(fun, new_list)
```

There's an overhead for splitting the list, but this is the simplest solution I can think of to reduce the number of times setup is called.

NOTE: x in this version of the code is a list of values, instead of a single value.

Comment: This isn't ideal because we lose the "load balancing" behaviour of Pool, but it would work. It also wouldn't work with iterating the output of map with eg. `imap_unordered`, but I didn't specify that in the question